# Cannot cast object 'null (Output)' error with gradle msbuild plugin

Tags: gradle, msbuild

I have a basic msbuild task setup in gradle build file. But when I try to run

```
gradle msbuild
```

gradle build fails with the following error:

```
Cannot cast object 'null (Output)' with class 'org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskOutputFilePropertyRegistration' to class 'org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskOutputs'
```

I believe our organization policy prohibits copy-paste operation on stackoverflow website. So I am unable to provide the complete stacktrace.

The entire contents of the gradle build file are as follows:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        repo_info
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.ullink.gradle:gradle-msbuild-plugin:2.9'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.ullink.msbuild'

msbuild {
    solutionFile = 'src/abc.sln'
    verbosity = 'detailed'
    version = '15.0'
    targets = ['Clean', 'Rebuild']
    destinationDir = 'build/msbuild/bin'
}
```

I am not able to use the latest version of the gradle-msbuild-plugin because I'm behind corporate firewall and 2.9 is the latest available.

Gradle version is 6.4.1.

Can anyone provide any info or solution to this issue?

NOTE: Because of the firewall, I'm unable to browse any other websites apart from stackoverflow, so I kindly request you to not provide links for other websites in your answers.